# Delphi REST.Client download corrupted PDF

Tags: rest, delphi, pdf

How can I save REST.Response.Content PDF file without corrupting it ?
After save, I run PDF and got only white screen. No content.

```
client.BaseURL := URL;

req.Params.Clear();
req.ClearBody();
req.Method := TRESTRequestMethod.rmGET;

  try
    req.Execute();
  except
    on e: ERESTException do
    begin
      //TODO: Error
    end;
  end;
```

In req.response.content I have PDF in string. But, always when I try to save it, it is corrupted.

//Edit

```
function TPDF.saveFile(): TResult;
var
  file: TStringStream;
  f: TFileStream;
  len: integer;
  bytes: TBytes;

begin

  file := TStringStream.Create();
  file.WriteString(response.Content);

  //f := TFileStream.Create(fileName, fmCreate);
  bytes := TEncoding.ANSI.GetBytes(response.Content); //i am tryied ANSI, UNICODE, UTF8

    //f.ReadData(bytes, response.ContentLength);
  //f.Position := 0;
  //f.WriteData(bytes, response.ContentLength);

  file.WriteData(bytes, response.ContentLength);
  file.SaveToFile(fileName);
//  TFile.WriteAllBytes(fileName, bytes);
//  file.SaveToFile(fileName);

  result := setResult(kbOK);
end;
```

Comment: Can you also show the code for saving Response.Content to a .pdf file?

Comment: PDF is binary format, you cannot store it in string just as-is.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar correct, however Content could be base64 encoded, and we don't know yet ... now we know :)

Comment: No, Content is not Base64 encodend. Server is CouchDB. Propably the problem is in string Encoded, or I should save it as binary somehow.

Comment: Take a look at [TRestResponse.RawBytes](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/REST.Client.TCustomRESTResponse.RawBytes) property, maybe it can be of some use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PDF is not using a single encoding format. Your server side code must send it as binary data, so that String conversions can not corrupt it. Also, your client must treat the response as binary data.

Comment: From server I get data as binary, content-type is 'application/json'. I can Read PDF directly from server by using browser. Maybe REST.Client have limitation, and better use TNetHTTPClient or TIdHTTP component ?

Comment: @InnerWorld monitor the HTTP traffic in the browser (with developer tools) and you will see that a pdf content type will be returned. The application/json response is likely caused by a missing content-type in the REST request sent from the client. So you have two things to do on the client side: setting the expected response content type, and accessing the response binary data (with TRestResponse.RawBytes)

Comment: Sorry, not application/json, but application/pdf. Too much jsons around :(

Comment: I accept this answer - I do have not seen TRESTResponse.RawBytes. TFile.WriteAllBytes() work now.

Answer (score 0):

Use `idHTTP` to directly get the response.

```
idHTTP.Get('http://example.com/thefile', myFileStream)
```